# Why can't QGIS recognize the right Layer CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a vector layer (shapefile), that I projected with ArcMap 10.4 into UTM33 (EPSG: 25833). If I load this layer in ArcMap, 25833 ist always recognized as the CS of the layer, as expected.

But when I load the same layer into QGIS 2.14, it can't recognize 25833. Instead it tells me the layer is allegedly 3006 (Sweref), which should be wrong.

What is the reason behind that problem and how can I prevent it? Happens quite often....

Here is the *.prj file content:
 PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM_zone_33N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID‌​["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532‌​92519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0]‌​,PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["fal‌​se_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Can you share the contents of the .prj file?

Comment: PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM_zone_33N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both EPSG codes you mention have identical parameter values. QGIS takes just the first that fits the values.

If you experience any problems, use `Set Layer CRS` to assign the EPSG:3006, then save to a new filename. QGIS creates a separate .qpj file where the EPSG code is stored explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what AndreJ answered:

I can susbtitute the saving to a new layer part when I use the "Define Current Projection" tool (Vector > Data Manegement Tools).

This means I don't need to produce more data by saving to a new shapefile. 
And QGIS will still recognize the right coordinate system also when I load the shapefile into other *.qgs projects.

Comment: Did you get the .qpj file? I was not sure if Define Current Projection would create it.